# X86: protected mode, GDT, IDT

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm, bochs

I've tried to execute simple kernel with a kolibri bootloader.
It's being loaded into 1000:0000.
I don't understand, what's wrong in this part:

```
...
; switch to PM
mov eax, cr0
or  al, 1
mov cr0, eax

use32
PROTECTED_ENTRY:
mov  ax, 00010000b  ; DATA
mov  ds, ax
mov  ss, ax
mov  esp, 0xFFFF

jmp $

mov  ax, 00011000b  ; VIDEO
mov  es, ax
mov  edi, 0

mov  esi, string
int 1

jmp $
```

'cause in debugger it looks like this
[image]

What's going on here? Why ES and DS aren't being changed?

P.S. i'm trying to get this kernel working with kolibri loader:
http://wasm.ru/article.php?article=ia32int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The processor does not automatically enter protected mode when you set the protected bit in `cr0`. It enters protected mode when `cs` is changed after that. The easiest way to do this is to insert a far jump immediately after writing to `cr0`.

```
mov cr0, eax
.db 066h
jmp CODE_SEGMENT:PROTECTED_ENTRY

use32
PROTECTED_ENTRY:
```

Hopefully I got that right. (I'm used to AT&T syntax.) That `.db` is an operand size override to allow a 32 bit address.

Answer (score 3):

Tee debugger does disassemble the 32bit code (you told the assembler to generate 32 bit code with the `use32` pseudo op) as 16 bit code. So the instruction `mov ax, 10h` is interpreted as `mov eax, d88e0010h`, where the `d88e` part is in reality the opcode for next instruction, `mov ds,ax`.

Similar for `mov esp, 0xffff`, which is interpreted as `mov sp, 0xffff` and the two additional zero bytes show up as the spurious `add byte ptr...` instruction.

What the processor actually executes, depends on its current state - is it in protected mode, real mode, flat mode etc. Look at the status registers to find out. Possibly you can tell the debugger to interpret the code different.